# Do plural names referring to a singular thing require a plural verb?

Tags: verbs, names, noun, place-names

Another question related to my geography of the Roman Empire which I am writing has arisen: during the time of Trajan, 117 AD, there were several provinces which had names in the plural, especially those which bordered or resided on the Alps, to name a few:

- *Alpēs Maritimae*
- *Alpēs Cottiae*
- *Alpēs Grāiae et Poenīnae*

In my geography itself, I have written several phrases similar to the following, note that the verbs are in the singular number:

> *Prīma hārum prōvinciārum, Alpēs Maritimae, ut nōmen dīcit, plūrimē montēs continet et lītora prope Ligusticum Mare.*

I wrote down the verbs in the singular while writing because it made sense to me; despite the fact that the names themselves are in the plural, they refer to singular things, provinces. However, as pointed out by [@JoonasIlmavirta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/79/joonas-ilmavirta) in [CONLOQVIVM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm), this might not be the case.

To sum up: when a name (or noun) has a plural form but refers to a singular thing, should any verb of which the name (or noun) is a subject be in the singular or plural?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plural place names should have plural verbs. A very simple case of this is Athenae, -arum (Athens). Here's an illuminating example from Cicero:

> in quam cum intueor, maxime mihi **occurrunt**, Attice, et quasi **lucent Athenae tuae**, qua in urbe primum se orator extulit primumque etiam monumentis et litteris oratio est coepta mandari. ([Cicero, *Brutus* 7](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2008.01.0544:chapter=7&highlight=athenis%2Cathenae))

Translation:

> And when I consider it [i.e. Greece], Atticus, your Athens occurs to me first and is like a light. For in this city the orator first arose, and also oratory first began to be preserved in writing and other memorials.

Shortly afterwards, he also uses the phrase *non nascentibus Athenis sed adultis* (= "in mature, not developing, Athens").

Two notes, then:

1. Grammatical agreement is preserved with plural place names.
2. But, as seen in "qua in urbe" above, you can use a singular noun to refer to the plural antecedent. In this case, you would use a singular verb to agree with the new noun.

And, for kicks, here's a pretty amusing example from Plautus that might have been intended for comical effect:

> Salvete, Athenae, quae nutrices Graeciae,
>   sperata erilis patria, te video libens. (Plautus, *Stichus* V.ii)

Translation:

> Hail (pl.), Athens, who are the nurses (pl.) of Greece,
>   my master's long-desired homeland (sing.). Gladly I see you (sing.).

Answer (score 8):

What you have written is grammatically correct and there is no conflict. The subject of *dicit* is *nomen* and of *continet* is *prima (provincia)*. Your actual question doesn't cover your example, but your request is perfectly clear.

There are two kinds of plural noun. Some, such as *hiberna* (winter quarters), *moenia* (town walls) and *tenebrae* (darkness) are only ever found in the plural form. The others take on a different meaning in the plural from that in the singular, such as *castrum* (fort) and *castra* (camp) ; *fortuna* (fortune, luck) and *fortunae* (possessions); *sal* (salt) and *sales* (wit).

Although we may translate the plurals into singular [English] nouns,in Latin  they always have all the attributes of a Latin plural. Plural-form nouns follow the same iron rule as all others : they must agree with their adjectives in number, gender and case.

Thus, in the first category we may find *legio XX in nova hiberna contendit* (where *legio* is the subject of a singular verb), but *nova hiberna pro legione XX ponuntur* (where *hiberna* is the subject  of the plural verb *ponuntur* in the passive voice).

And in the second category : in *duo castra in ripa ponent* (where the plural-form *castra* is the object, and [they] the singular subject  of a verb in the singular) ; but *castra in ripa ponentur* requires a plural verb, because the subject *castra* is the subject of a verb in the passive voice.

Just an observation : in poetry we sometimes see the plural of words, that are normally used in the singular, used in the plural with singular meaning : sometimes it is a device to conform to standard metrical form, and sometimes it is purely for poetical effect (as we might say, 'whimsical'). This has its counterpart in English, for example ' the snow that is falling' or 'the snows of yesterday'. But the iron rule on agreement still applies : *nix cadit* or *nives cadunt*.

Comment: Huh, I hadn't taken the time to look back and realize that I had written *Alpēs Maritimae* in apposition to *prīma [...]*. Thanks for pointing that out, and good answer! :)